# Else statement seems to be ignored in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm creating a login and I've encountered an issue. I want an error message to appear if the user enters an incorrect username and/or password, specifically if both don't match what's in the DB the user will be prompted that they have entered an incorrect username/password.

It seems as if my else statement is ignored whenever I run the code. My if statement works, I've tested it. But no matter what I echo in the else clause,  it's not being accessed. I've tried restructuring the js the php is tied to, I've tried Stack Overflow solutions to similar issues to no avail. I've tested the code by stepping through it and when the if statement is true "sas" is echoed, when if is not true (else) "" is echoed. No error messages on the console. Perhaps there's something wrong with the logic of what I'm trying here.

I'm using Malsup's jQuery form plugin to submit login form asynchronously. I've reduced some of non essential (there may be more I know) html and js but included the files for good measure.

## PHP

```
    <?php
    $host     = "meh"; // Host name 
    $username = "blah"; // Mysql username 
    $password = "pft"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name  = "doh"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name = "leh"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];

    // To protect MySQL injection
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $mypassword);
    $sql        = "SELECT FirstName, Password FROM $tbl_name WHERE FirstName= ? AND Password= ? ";
    //prepare and bind paramters
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $myusername, $mypassword);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($returnedusername, $returnedpassword);

        //fetch $stmt results
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if (isset($returnedusername) && isset($returnedpassword) && $returnedusername === $myusername && $returnedpassword === $mypassword) {
                session_register("myusername");
                session_register("mypassword");
                //header("location:login_success.php");
                echo "sas";
            } else {//I DONT THIS PART IS BEING RUN...NOT SURE THOUGH IF LOOKING AT WRONG PART OF CODE
                echo $_POST['loginError'];//loginError found in html, will be error message
            } 
        } //end while

    } //end if
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

### JS

```
$('document').ready(function() { 

    var  loginForm = $("#form1");

    //Will load user's name into page heading (from local storage)
    function storeUsername() {
        window.alert("You made it in the function");//testing to see if code is run
        if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
            // Store the user's first name as localStorage Object
            var inputUsername = document.getElementById("myusername");
            localStorage.username = inputUsername.value;
            window.alert(localStorage.username);
        }
    }

    var options = {
        target: '#loginError',
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit, // pre-submit callback 
        success: afterSuccess
    };

    //Submit form via ajax
    // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#form1').submit(function() {

        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

        return false;
    });

    //after succesful upload
    function afterSuccess() {

        var flag = $("#loginError");
        var flagContents = flag.html();

        if (flagContents == "sas") {
            window.location.href = "login_success.php";
            //remove the imgPlaceHolder element

        } else {
            flag.fadeIn('slow');//error message will fade In
        }
    }
    function beforeSubmit() {
        //check whether browser fully supports all File API
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            storeUsername();

        } else {
            //Output error to older unsupported browsers that doesn't support HTML5 File API
            alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/generalJS/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="100" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><strong> Login </strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username:
                                <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" required> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password:
                                <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword" required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" name="Submit" value="Login"></input>
                        <div id="loginError" name="loginError" style="display:none" value="**Username or password incorrect**"></div>
                        <!--Php script will provide an error is login fails. It will get the outcome from checklogin, fetch reason from "password"-->
                    </table>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSOnload() {
        var element1 = document.createElement("script");
        element1.src = "../js/login.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element1);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSOnload;
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question down to the **smallest program necessary to reproduce the issue**. You've posted too much code for us to easily find the issue. Slim the program down as much as possible while still being able to reproduce the issue then post that code. See also: [mcve]

Comment: You probably aren't entering the `while` because there is nothing to fetch. Check if you enter the `while` on an instance where you expect the `else` to fire.

Comment: @chris85 thank you for making an honest attempt to help me! I understand the code may look like a lot at a glance but if you read what I wrote then you'll be able to zero in on issue, you did this.

Comment: @chris85 So the code is not fetching anything bc it's returning nothing on the query so there's no `while` to `fetch()`... bc there's nothing there! These are the changes I made to the php: I'm storing the results after binding `$stmt->store_result(); ` , then I check if the query returns any rows at all and if not I can then prompt the user of an incorrect entry `if ($stmt->num_rows > 0){//check if input info matches db info then redir to profile page}; else "wrong login info..." ` I also changed the echo to a string message.`echo 'wrong login info...' ` It all works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue:

```
<div id="loginError" name="loginError" style="display:none" value="**Username or password incorrect**"></div>
```

Change it to:

```
<input id="loginError" name="loginError" style="display:none" value="**Username or password incorrect**" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Also, what is the JS jquery function "ajaxSubmit" ?

Comment: Also you shouldn't store the username in a cookie or local storage as this can be edited by the user on client side, instead, rely on php session variables ($_SESSION), don't forget to put a session_start(); at the beginning of your php header

Comment: ajaxSubmit is a function from a plugin I'm using (malsup jQuery Form), so it's not an API function. @chris85 actually hit the nail on the head, the issue was in my query logic. Everything works as intended, thanks for the tip on session variables. That particular instance of the username will not be stored anywhere but webstorage (usernames are stored in DB so I could always populate the username upon successful login) as it intention is solely to display a username on the following page, nevertheless I will heed your advice. Thanks Luc, I appreciate the help :) !